# Trying to access toolbar button is nil

Tags: javascript, ui-automation

I have been working on writing some automation scripts for an app I am writing, and have been trying to get the following function to work. I was able to finally get it to complete correctly, but with some different code. The following two code snippets are the same, in my mind, but only the FIRST one seems to work. I would love some insight as to why. Is it my JavaScript skills (which are weak, at best), or something specific to UIAutomation?

```
// Define some global variables -- THIS WORKS
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var app = target.frontMostApp().mainWindow();
var toolbarButtons = app.toolbar().buttons();
toolbarButtons["Back"].tap();
```

This fails...

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var app = target.frontMostApp().mainWindow();
var backButton = app.toolbar().buttons()["Back"];
backButton.tap();
```

The second (failing) code snippet says that I'm getting a nil value for the button. If someone could help point out why this second approach isn't correct, I'd greatly appreciate it. I have to tap the back button a number of times, and backButton.tap() just seems cleaner.

UPDATE: Below is the exact code that is failing

```
// Define some global variables
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var app = target.frontMostApp().mainWindow();

// List everything we see
UIALogger.logStart("Logging app...");
app.logElementTree();
UIALogger.logPass();

// Function for moving into and out of every home screen option
var homeToViewAndBack = function() {
    var backButton = app.toolbar().buttons()["Back"];
    // Let's go down the list of buttons

    app.buttons()["VideoHomeButton"].tap();
    backButton.tap();

    UIALogger.logPass("Basic navigation works.");
}

// Call our functions
homeToViewAndBack();
```

This give an error " Script threw an uncaught JavaScript error: Cannot perform action on invalid element: UIAElementNil from target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().toolbar().buttons()["Back"]". However, the code in the first snippet above works like a charm.

To confirm again, I changed the text on the back button to "Home" and tried the following code...the first call to the back button works, but the second fails:

```
var homeToViewAndBack = function() {
var toolbarButtons = app.toolbar().buttons();
var backButton = app.toolbar().buttons()["Home"];
// Let's go down the list of buttons
app.buttons()[0].tap();
toolbarButtons["Home"].tap();

app.buttons()[1].tap();
backButton.tap();

UIALogger.logPass("Basic navigation works.");
}
```

Comment: Running mockups of your scenario, both succeeded for me. Could you provide a live/jsfiddle example of the issue?